# saving remote json data to the device

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I'am new to programming. I successfully parse a json data and display it. I want to refresh the data every day, so user will not download the same data every time app starts. I couldn't find a useful tutorial for this...

Also my cell have images, is there a way to save only the images?

Thanks

```
func refreshArticles(){
        loadArticles()
    }

    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
    var articles: [JSON]? = []
    var moreArticles: [JSON]? = []
    var yazarinArticles: [JSON]? = []

    func loadArticles(currentPage:Int=1){            
        let url = "http://abc" + String(currentPage)
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
            if (json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["articles"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{

                    self.articles = data
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.view.hideLoading()
                    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    self.title = "Makaleler"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadArticles()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Save your json and image in document directory and check for availability when you start application.

Comment: could you please give a code sample?